# session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 79 with Octopus

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, npm, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to run "ng e2e" command with octopus with following configuration but getting below error all the time:

```
[07:20:37] E/launcher - session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 79
  (Driver info: chromedriver=79.0.3945.16 (93fcc21110c10dbbd49bbff8f472335360e31d05-refs/branch-heads/3945@{#262}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)
[07:20:37] E/launcher - SessionNotCreatedError: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 79
  (Driver info: chromedriver=79.0.3945.16 (93fcc21110c10dbbd49bbff8f472335360e31d05-refs/branch-heads/3945@{#262}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:546:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:509:13)
    at D:\a\1\s\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:441:30
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:769:24)
    at Function.createSession (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\chrome.js:761:15)
    at Direct.getNewDriver (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\protractor\built\driverProviders\direct.js:77:33)
    at Runner.createBrowser (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:195:43)
    at D:\a\1\s\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:339:29
    at _fulfilled (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
    at D:\a\1\s\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
    at D:\a\1\s\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:556:49
    at runSingle (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
[07:20:37] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
An unexpected error occurred: undefined
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! rebar-spa-v2-template@0.0.3 e2e: `ng e2e`
```

Configuration is:

- user-agent = "npm/6.12.1 node/v12.13.1 win32 x64"

Protractor.conf.js:

```
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
      args: ['--headless', '--disable-gpu', '--window-size=800,600']
    }
  },
```

Package.json: tried with both of solution

postinstall: `webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome 79.0.3945.36`

or

postinstall: `cd ./node_modules/protractor && npm i webdriver-manager@latest`

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This error message...

```
session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 79 (Driver info: chromedriver=79.0.3945.16 (93fcc21110c10dbbd49bbff8f472335360e31d05-refs/branch-heads/3945@{#262}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **Browsing Context** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=79.0.3945.16*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=79.0.3945.16*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/79.0.3945.16/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v79**

- Presumably you are using a *Chrome* with a version other then *chrome= 79.0*
- Possibly the following command  fails:

  ```
  webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome 79.0.3945.36
  ```

So there is a clear mismatch between the *ChromeDriver v79.0* and your current *Chrome Browser*

---

### Solution

Ensure the following mentioned steps will solve the issue:

- You may need to clean up once:

  ```
  webdriver-manager clean
  ```
- You have the latest version of [webdriver-manager](/questions/tagged/webdriver-manager) and you can install the same using the command:

  ```
  webdriver-manager@latest --save
  ```
- Execute the following command will solve your issue:

  ```
  webdriver-manager update
  ```
- Upgrade *Chrome* to the latest stable release:

  ```
  webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome 79.0.3945.88
  ```

Comment: Above solution is working fine on localhost but with octopus is not working

Comment: I have used above steps like below but still not working; It seems webdriver-manager not updating anyhow.   
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "webdriver-manager clean && npm install webdriver-manager@latest && webdriver-manager update && webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome 79.0.3945.88"
  },

Comment: Try using an older version of chrome `--chrome --versions.chrome=78.0.3904.97`

Answer (score 0):

I got this message when my system downloaded Chrome 90 in the background, even though my browser still said 89 (to be fair it was prompting me to update). I tried a few things but in the end I just ran `npm uninstall chromedriver` and then `npm install chromedriver` and everything started working again. Not ideal but I'm happy my tests are able to run.

EDIT:

I noticed that running the above commands updated my package.json file so it now said `"chromedriver": "^90.0.0"` in it. I'm guessing I could have made that version change myself and run `npm install chromedriver` to download the updated driver file. I'll try that next time.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for me was that chromedriver was installed globally. Need just do `npm i chromedriver -g`